# Python 3.7 - Pygame 1.9.4

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Whenever I execute my python code, using the python's shell, pygame is always retrieving this message:

```
#pygame 1.9.4#
#Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html#
```

How do I removed it? It's very annoying because I am analysing some data and the message is always popping out before what I really need to look at.

Comment: * I am analysing.

Comment: Thanks! for replying!